# configure jetty for hot deployment in spring boot

Tags: jetty, spring-boot

How do I configure jetty for hot deployment, i.e. set intervalScan ?
Is it possible set from properties file?
I've read the documentation, but it's only explain to setting basic configuration such as port,context path,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot doesn't expose all Jetty features via external properties, but you should have access to all the Java APIs. Having said that, I doubt if "intervalScan" is very useful to you for thymeleaf with the default Boot settings because it's a Jetty setting related to the Servlet context (as far as I understand) and Boot prefers you to load templates from the classpath. Your IDE should allow you to build automatically (ie update the classpath when resources change), or the Gradle and Maven tooling from Boot can be used on the command line.